# How set tcl language parsing rules in function list - notepad++ plugin

Tags: tcl, notepad++

I have tried to do this refering to following link.
http://skypher.com/index.php/2008/07/28/function-list-for-php/
But no success.
Can you help me please.
It will be great if namesapces also parsed.

Comment: What version of Notepad and Function List are you using?  With my install, Notepad++ 5.0.3 and Function List 1.2 TCL function listing just works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind,
Notepad+= 5.4.5 unicode and function list 2.0 beta. I have succeded with

```
<Group name="Global Procedures" subgroup="" icon="8" child="16" autoexp="4" matchcase="0" fendtobbeg="" bbegtobend="" keywords=""> <Rules regexbeg="^proc\s+" regexfunc="[\w_]+" regexend="" bodybegin="{" bodyend="}" sep="" /> </Group> <Group name="Namespaces" subgroup="" icon="0" child="0" autoexp="4" matchcase="1" fendtobbeg="" bbegtobend="" keywords=""> <Rules regexbeg="^namespace\s+eval\s+::" regexfunc="[\w_]+" regexend="" bodybegin="" bodyend="" sep="" /> </Group>
```